# `Drag component here` box is coming like pixel in AEM

Tags: aem, aem-6

What can be reason in AEM in edit mode and i am Admin user. In my page `Drag component here` is coming like dot insist of whole box.

[image]

But it should look like this. If i inspect and change its height we can see the original component. What can be reason for this.

[image]

Comment: It coould be an issue with your used html and css.

Comment: Does it happen on all components or is a very specific component?

Comment: It happens in all component, May be the template can be issue. I got idea , i am exploring it. Let see i find solution to that.